# make a before_filter with current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

I would like to make a before_filter on a controller with the method :current_user
And it works...
But I have an admin boolean in the user's attributes and I would like that only the users who have this boolean at "true" use the controller.
How can I do that ?

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use any method that returns a boolean value as a `before_filter` in rails. So in your case, just make a method like

```
def is_admin?
  return (current_user && current_user.admin?)
end
```

and then call `before_filter is_admin?` at the top of your controller with the actions you want to filter.

Note that short-circuit evaluation of `&&` ensures that `admin?` is not called on `current_user` if it is nil.

Comment: it doesn't work... i got this error, the return of the function is_admin is false but the action index work...

Comment: Can you show me your `is_admin` function and the `before_filter` line you used? It should be one of the first lines in your controller, and it should look like `before_filter is_admin?`

Comment: def is_admin?
  return (current_user && current_user.admin?)
end  this is the is_admin? method and the before_filter link is before_filter :is_admin?

Comment: Thats strange. Make sure the `before_filter` line is only in the specific controller that you want to filter, not in `ApplicationController`, and that the `is_admin?` method is in the same controller. If that doesn't fix it, then post the code from the controller in your question.

Comment: no the is_admin? method is in application controller, and the before_filter is in the specific controller. thanks for your help